# Upper bound for generalized harmonic number wih negative exponent

Tags: nt.number-theory

Hi, 
I need an upper bound for the generalized harmonic number with negative exponents, i.e:

$$H_{n,r}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^r}$$

where $r<0$ especially, I need a bound for $$r=-\frac{1}{2}$$ Has anyone an idea whether those bounds exist?
Thanks!

PS: I've seen the related question, but the answer only deals with $$r>0$$

Comment: Isn't $\int^{n+1}_1 x^{-r}dx$ sufficient for your purposes?


Comment: The tails of such sums are easily bounded by integrals. 

Comment: A good question, but not of research interest (unless you want bounds better than the best currently known). This website is for research; try math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @charles: what do you mean by tails? These are all divergent...

Comment: Sadly, the integral isn't good enough... but I'm afraid my bound isn't working anyway... :-(

Comment: It could really help if you provide some context. What type/quality of bound would you need? Or, is your last comment to be understood that the question is no longer relevant (say, since the application you had in mind does not work no matter the bound for this sum)?